# DolphinDB: Create multiple in-memory tables with the same schema

Tags: create-table, multiple-tables, dolphindb

I want to create 100 tables in batches and preallocate enough underlying memory for them. In addition to using the for loop to dynamically add elements, is there any way more convenient?

//initialize tables `list_tables`

```
 list_tables=[table(150000:0, `trade_day`secu_code`factor_value, `INT`INT`DOUBLE),
       table(150000:0, `trade_day`secu_code`factor_value, `INT`INT`DOUBLE),
       table(150000:0, `trade_day`secu_code`factor_value, `INT`INT`DOUBLE),
       table(150000:0, `trade_day`secu_code`factor_value, `INT`INT`DOUBLE),
       table(150000:0, `trade_day`secu_code`factor_value, `INT`INT`DOUBLE)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use function `each` and `lambda` to create multiple tables.

```
list_tables=each(x->table(150000:0, `trade_day`secu_code`factor_value, `INT`INT`DOUBLE),1..100)
>list_tables[0];
trade_day secu_code factor_value
--------- --------- ------------
```